# ASP.NET 400 and 403 errors when trying to hit API endpoint from remote machine on same network

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET project running on a machine (A) at `localhost:54942` on my network.

Trying to hit the endpoint on A itself with Postman (or browser) gives different results based on the url.

- `localhost:54942/api/endpoint` returns expected value
- `[ip address/machine name]:54942/api/endpoint` returns `Error 400: The request hostname is invalid`
- `[ip address/machine name]:54942/api/endpoint` with `Host: localhost` in the header returns expected value

When trying to hit the endpoint from another machine (B) on the network I get the following responses:

- `[ip address/machine name]:54942/api/endpoint` return `Error 400: The request hostname is invalid`
- `[ip address/machine name]:54942/api/endpoint` with `Host: localhost` in the header returns `Error 403: The request URL is forbidden`

I'm not providing credentials on either machine, so I'm not sure why there's no `403` response on A, but there is on B. I've searched a bit on this and haven't really found much. I've removed `localhost` from my bindings in `applicationhost.config` where it was set to `bindingInformation="*:54942:localhost"` and that did nothing. I've changed some of the `sectionGroup` `overrideModeDefault` values to no avail. I've created a rule in `web.config` to allow all users to `api/endpoint` and that also did nothing.

I'm really at a loss for how to resolve this.

Comment: How are you hosting the application? IIS? The 400 sounds like an error from the hosting provider not the application.

Comment: Using IIS Express via Visual Studio.

Comment: Most likely IIS _Express_ won't allow non-localhost traffic on the port. Try another hosting provider, like regular IIS.